# Manipulating only the denominator in the solution of a fourth order equation

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I wrote the code bellow to solve a fourth order equation:

```
expr = Simplify[
  1/40 (12 dr (-1 + 15 e ro) - 
     s) (10 s (4 s^2 - 
        12 dr (4 (-1 + 15 e ro) s + 
           3 k^2 (-1 + 4000 dc (-1 + 15 e ro) - 5 e ro (-3 + 4 s))) + 
        k^2 (3 (3 + 4000 dc - 30 e ro) s + 2000000 v^2)) + 
     alpha ro (4 s^2 + 
        12 dr (4 s - 60 e ro s + 
           k^2 (3 - 40000 c tr + 15 e ro (-3 + 4 s + 40000 c tr))) + 
        k^2 (s (9 - 90 e ro - 40000 c tr) + 
           2000000 v (v - 10 c xr))))]

sol = Solve[expr == 0, s];
```

The output is 4 solutions for parameter called `s`.

**I want to manipulate only the [`Denominator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Denominator.html) to replace with zero each `k` which appears in the denominator of each solution.**

Comment: You can use `solutions /. k->0`, do you mean that?

Comment: No. I want to put k in the denominator of each solution equal to zero. Not both the denominator and nominator.@DavidBaghdasaryan

Comment: @rhermans Is it clear?

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. Maybe one can do something before solving the equation or while solving it

Comment: Maybe `MapAt[Numerator[#]/(Denominator[#] /. k -> 0) &@ Together[#] &, solutions, {All, 1, 2}]`?  (Assuming it gets the denominator you want.)

Comment: It seems that the question is formulated not carefully enough. In these solutions there are no COMMON denominators that would represent complex functions involving k. However, some solutions consist of several terms, each one having such a denominator. Can it be that the author wants to operate on such terms separately?

Answer (score 1):

In general for a given expression let's say

```
sol = PadeApproximant[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

you could do extract [`Numerator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Numerator.html) and [`Denominator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Denominator.html), therefore you could operate in one of them before rebuilding the expression.

```
Numerator[sol]/ReplaceAll[Denominator[sol], x -> 1]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

In your case (after comment by  @MichaelE2) first use [`Together`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Together.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
solutions = Map[Together, (s /. Solve[yourexpression == 0, s])]
```

and then

```
 Map[Numerator[#]/ReplaceAll[Denominator[#], k -> 0] &, solutions]
```

Comment: The problem is that I can not find denominator

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Could you do something with the solutions that their complicated appearance become more simpler? Simplify don't do anything

Comment: It doesn't seem to simplify any more. have a read [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SimplifyingAlgebraicExpressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I executed this statement, which just tacks a `Simplify` onto the solving...

```
sol = s /. Solve[expr == 0, s] // Simplify
```

After doing this, here are the Denominators for the 4 solutions. No `k` variable in them.

```
Map[Denominator, sol]

(*  {1, 60, 480, 480}  *)
```

EDIT

Played with it some more, calling Together to get common denominators

```
(Map[Denominator[Together[#]] &, sol] /. k -> 0) //Simplify//TableForm
```

The results are 1 for the first denominator, and then for the 2nd through 4th terms, the same term but scaled by either 120(2nd term) or 240 (3rd and 4th).

```
1

120 (180 Sqrt[3]
 Sqrt[-alpha^2 dr^2 ro^2 (1 - 15 e ro)^2 (alpha ro + 
   120 dr (-1 + 15 e ro))^2] + (alpha ro + 
  60 dr (-1 + 15 e ro)) (-alpha ro + 
  120 dr (-1 + 15 e ro)) (alpha ro + 240 dr (-1 + 15 e ro)))^(1/3)

240 (180 Sqrt[3]
 Sqrt[-alpha^2 dr^2 ro^2 (1 - 15 e ro)^2 (alpha ro + 
   120 dr (-1 + 15 e ro))^2] + (alpha ro + 
  60 dr (-1 + 15 e ro)) (-alpha ro + 
  120 dr (-1 + 15 e ro)) (alpha ro + 240 dr (-1 + 15 e ro)))^(1/3)

240 (180 Sqrt[3]
 Sqrt[-alpha^2 dr^2 ro^2 (1 - 15 e ro)^2 (alpha ro + 
   120 dr (-1 + 15 e ro))^2] + (alpha ro + 
  60 dr (-1 + 15 e ro)) (-alpha ro + 
  120 dr (-1 + 15 e ro)) (alpha ro + 240 dr (-1 + 15 e ro)))^(1/3)
```