# Mathematica can not determine the nominator in some cases

Tags: equation-solving

I wrote below code to solve a fourth order equation that is:

```
Solve[1/40 (12 dr (-1 + 15 e ro) - 
 s) (10 s (4 s^2 - 
    12 dr (4 (-1 + 15 e ro) s + 
       3 k^2 (-1 + 4000 dc (-1 + 15 e ro) - 5 e ro (-3 + 4 s))) + 
    k^2 (3 (3 + 4000 dc - 30 e ro) s + 2000000 v^2)) + 
 alpha ro (4 s^2 + 
    12 dr (4 s - 60 e ro s + 
       k^2 (3 - 40000 c tr + 15 e ro (-3 + 4 s + 40000 c tr))) + 
    k^2 (s (9 - 90 e ro - 40000 c tr) + 
       2000000 v (v - 10 c xr)))) == 0, s]
```

the output is 4 solution for the parameter called s. I want to put each k which appears in the denominator of each solution equal to zero. So I decide to find the nominator and denominator of each solution, put k in denominator equal to zero and then divide nominator and new denominator. But as the solutions are complicated, it can not find denominator.
How can I put k in the denominator equal to zero?

Comment: Does [`Together`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Together.html) help?

Comment: `Numerator[#]/(Denominator[#] /. k -> 0) & /@ (s /. soln)`

Comment: This is already at [146081](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146081). Do yo need a new question for this? Just edit your original question to explain the problem.